# How to Select Inline DropDown list are Buttons?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Using selenium keywords How to select inline drop down list are buttons?
Here is my inspected HTML code snippet please help me to which Selenium keywords used to select?

**HTML code** :

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="d-inline-block dropdown show">
       <button _ngcontent-c4="" data-toggle="dropdown" id="SomeIdname" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center" ariaexpanded="true">
       <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="mr-auto">Example1</span>
       </button>
       <div _ngcontent-c4="" aria-labelledby="SomeLabes" class="dropdown- menu w-100 show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(-17px, 51px, 0px);">
       <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="dropdown-item ng-star-inserted active" ng- reflect-klass="dropdown-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Example1</button>
       <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="dropdown-item ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect- klass="dropdown-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Example2</button>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which one you want to select ?

Comment: I have only Two buttons one Example1 and Example2, Example1 is an active button that is automatically class="mr-auto" updated. Now I want to select Example2 when we select  Example2 that will be the change to class="mr-auto" and active button.

Comment: when we click the dropdown button "ariaexpanded='true' " also changes to the true to false(false to true).

Comment: I want to select the Example2 button in the drop-down list

Comment: I have made a sample passive site with your HTML, and I see 3 buttons, `Example1` , `Example1`, `Example2`. Is it correct ?

Comment: No, We have only two buttons, which is the active button that is updated to the span tag button field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this xpath :

```
//button[text()='Example2']
```

Let me know if you have any more concerns.

Comment: Ohhh, Thank you!  Yep, It's working but it automatically switches back to the previously active button only.

Comment: Create two web element, for button 1 use `//button[text()='Example1']` , for button 2 use `//button[text()='Example2']`

Comment: When we click that Eaxmple2 button that route entire web page, after few seconds only web page body switches back to the Example1 button web page

Comment: What is your use case ? you wanna click on Example1 then you wanna click on Example2

Comment: No, By default we see Example1 and When we click example2 that will redirect to the entire application relating to the Example2 web pages in the application portal. Again when we click Example1 that will want to redirect to an entire application relating to example1

Comment: In the case when we click the example2 that will be going to redirect  entire 
 only a few seconds application after the switch back (redirect) to the application relating to example1 webpages but even though example2 button  shows active

Comment: Thank you! for your approaches.

Answer (score 0):

After used "SeleniumLibrary.Reload Page" keyword its not redirect back to the Example1 page

```
     Click Button                    xpath://*[@id="SomeIdname"]   
     Click Button                    xpath://button[text()='Example2']
     SeleniumLibrary.Reload Page
```